# Change the li class via js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna a simple Js to when click on the respective li to execute changeBrasaoCamisa function, alto put "ativo" in the css class.

I tried with no sucess:

```
$("ul li").on("click", function() {
   $("li").removeClass("ativo");
   $(this).addClass("ativo");
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="dorco">
  <ul style="list-style-type: none; cursor: pointer;">
    <li class="posEscudo esquerda ativo" a href="#" onclick='changeBrasaoCamisa("esquerda")'>
      <img src="./imagens/btEscudoEsquerda.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="posEscudo ombro" a href="#" onclick='changeBrasaoCamisa("ombro")'>
      <img src="./imagens/btEscudoOmbro.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="posEscudo centro" a href="#" onclick='changeBrasaoCamisa("centro")'>
      <img src="./imagens/btEscudoCentro.png" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use an `onclick` event, it's very outdated. Your method of adding an unobtrusive handler is correct [and does work](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ne7d2roc/). What's your issue with it? If the class does not seem to be applied, check that the rules are specific enough to override any already set, and check the console for errors.

Comment: Where is your script in relation to your markup?  It's not in a document ready so if it appears before the markup it will not find the elements to bind on

Comment: Just don´t add the "ativo" class on the li

Comment: Huh?  The last line of your handler is explicitly putting that class on the li.  This is very confusing.

Comment: In the console appear: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Tks to you all. Was just to adjust some folder/files permissions and put the script after the divs. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works - I have made a simplified example to demonstrate:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class=" ativo">
      a
    </li>
    <li>
      b
    </li>
    <li>
      c
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ativo {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

JS:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
   $("li").removeClass("ativo");
   $(this).addClass("ativo");
});
```

See [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/c9ayynke/)